# Angular2: Using DynamicComponentLoader from a service

Tags: angular

Use case: I am building a toast notification service, `ToastService`. I want to be able to inject this service into components to create new toasts.

I have created a `Toast` component which represents a single notification:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'toast',
    template: `<div>This is a notification</div>`
})
export class Toast {}
```

And the I want to be able to call `toastService.show(myMessage);` to display a toast from one of my components.

So far my `ToastService` looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ToastService{

    constructor(private loader: DynamicComponentLoader) {}

    show(message: string) {
        this.loader.loadNextToLocation(
            Toast,
            /* location: ElementRef - how do I get one? I want to load it into the body */
        )
        .then((ref: ComponentRef) => {
            console.log('loaded toast!');
        });
    }
}
```

I would ideally like to load the toast as a child of the `body` element, to ensure it is always on top of the rest of the app elements.

How is this possible? Or is there a better approach? I tried to figure out how they do it in the [angular2 material repo](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/core/portal/portal.ts), but it is just too hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [angular-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/) project. The requirements for modal are similar to modal dialog.

Specifically check [modal.ts](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/src/components/angular2-modal/providers/Modal.ts) file, how `open` method gets hold of the root component to show a dialog.

```
public open(componentType: FunctionConstructor, bindings: ResolvedProvider[],
                config?: ModalConfig): Promise<ModalDialogInstance> {
        // TODO: appRef.injector.get(APP_COMPONENT) Doesn't work.
        // When it does replace with the hack below.
        //let myElementRef = this.appRef.injector.get(APP_COMPONENT).location;
        let elementRef: ElementRef = (<any>this.appRef)._rootComponents[0].location;

        return this.openInside(componentType, elementRef, null, bindings, config);
    }
```

`appRef` is `ApplicationRef` class injected in costructor and stores the reference to the running application.

```
  constructor(private componentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, private appRef: ApplicationRef,
                @Optional() defaultConfig: ModalConfig) {
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the kind of think I have been attempting. Looks good, but I am concerned about the use of a private API.

Comment: And for this very reason angular-modal has this warning :)  You too can have a TODO.

Comment: Actually there is another hack where you can store the root component reference in some global variable and use that reference. No DI involved.

Comment: In this case, I am building a re-usable library so I cannot rely on things like storing global references to the root component. 

Your answer is probably the correct answer to my question, so I will mark it as such. However, I get the feeling my question (and this approach) may not be the "angular 2 way" to do this. Hard to tell with so few canonical examples out there.

Comment: Angular2 still does not have a easy mechanism to augment the component tree dynamically.What @Gunter is mention is a better solution but i believe requires one to inject the `Toast ` component into the tree dynamically (as it is a library)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to get `ElementRef` into a service. You wouldn't even know if the `ElementRef` is still valid when you try to use it.

Instead I would add a `Toast` component "somewhere" that listens to updates from an `Observable` in `ToastService` and displays the components it gets passed from the `Observable` as events.

If you want the `Toast` component to be added outside of your `AppComponent` you can bootstrap it as a distinct Angular application.

In this case you need to create the shared service instance before bootstrapping and provide the same instance to both "applications" like:

```
let toastService = new ToastService();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(ToastService, {useValue: toastService})]);
bootstrap(Toast, [provide(ToastService, {useValue: toastService})]);
```

Comment: Perhaps I am thinking too much in terms of my ng1 experience. The solution with an external component which listens to a stream sounds promising - I'll attempt a solution based on that. Although this answer may prove to be the correct solution for my overall goal, I think the other one from @Chandermani actually answers the question. Probably a case of an "XY problem" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378